# why is there a expecting comma error in y86 code

Tags: y86

Can someone tell me why I might be getting these errors. when I try to run in ./yas -

```
Error on line 22: Expecting Register ID
Line 22, Byte 0x0032:      subl $24, %esp
Error on line 24: Expecting Register ID
Line 24, Byte 0x0036:      subl $0,8(%ebp)
Error on line 27: Expecting Register ID
Line 27, Byte 0x0043:      mrmovl $0, -20(%ebp)
Error on line 33: Expecting Comma
Line 33, Byte 0x005a:      mrmovl %eax, -8(%ebp)
Error on line 38: Expecting Register ID
Line 38, Byte 0x0077:      mrmovl (%eax), -4(%ebp)
Error on line 43: Expecting Comma
Line 43, Byte 0x0091:      mrmovl %edx, -20(%ebp)
```

There is a subl instruction in y86 right?
any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am only starting to learn y86, but I think I can give you a hand:

Problem Line 22) The reason that the first two subl operations are failing is because you are only able to perform subl operations between two registers (think of it as a two's compliment negation applied to the first register, then added to the second, only changing the second register's value).
Solution Line 22) Use the stack to store a register's value and load the constant for subtraction. Don't forget to restore the register with a pop!

```
pushl %edx
irmovl $24, %edx
subl %edx, %exp
popl %edx
```

Problem Line 24) A similar problem with the subl requiring a register. However, you are also trying to change directly a value in the memory (since it is the second argument being changed).
Solution Line 24) Use the stack to store two register values and load the constant for subtraction and load the value from memory. Don't forget to restore the register with pops!

```
pushl %edx              # edx first in
pushl %ebx              # ebx last in
mrmovl 8(%ebp), %ebx    #move memory integer to ebx
subl %edx, %ebx
rmmovl %ebx, 8(%ebp)    #move register integer to memory
popl %ebx               # ebx first out
popl %edx               # edx last out
```

Problem Lines 27 && 38) An integer transfer from Memory to Register uses an MRmovl operation (emphasis on M and R instead of R to M in a rmmovl operation).
Solution Lines 27 && 38) To use constants, use the previous stack tricks. Also, switch the ordering since the memory address of -20(%ebp) must be the first parameter.

Problems Lines 33 && 43) See problem above, except now a register is indeed being used (no stack needed).
Solution Lines 33 && 43) Same as before, swap parameters to load the memory value into register %eax.

Hopefully this clears up some instructions with y86 (irmovl from Immediate Value to register, rmmovl from register to memory, and mrmovl from memory to register) as well as introduces ways to use the stack to manage temporary values.